# ASP NET MVC 4 collection is null on post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I read most of Google :-), but I can't proceed. The collection on my object is and stays null on post, whatever I do.

My Model:

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public IList<ArticleItemViewModel> ArtikelListe { get; set; }

    public decimal GesamtpreisNetto { get; set; }
    public decimal MwSt { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ArticleItemViewModel
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Artikelname { get; set; }
    public string Artikelname_EN { get; set; }

    public string Information { get; set; }
    public string Information_EN { get; set; }

    public decimal Preis { get; set; }

    public bool MitAnzahl { get; set; }
    public bool IstKategorie { get; set; }

    public int Anzahl { get; set; }
    public bool Checkbox { get; set; }

    public int Reihenfolge { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Next", "Article", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EventId)

<input type="hidden" name="ArtikelListe" />

for (var i = 0; i < Model.ArtikelListe.Count; i++)
//  foreach (EventManager.ViewModels.ArticleItemViewModel artikelItem in Model.ArtikelListe)
{               
    <div>
        <div>
            @if (Model.ArtikelListe[i].IstKategorie)
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Artikelname)<br />  
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Information)
            }
            else
            {
                if (Model.ArtikelListe[i].MitAnzahl)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl, new { @class = "field text fn" })
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl)                     
                }

                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Artikelname)<br />  
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Information)
            }        
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

On post, I get my Viewmodel back and it has a Collection of ArtikelListe with 15 items (thats correct), but these are all null!

In my HTTP Header I get the following post data:

```
EventId:824e7f3c-7190-4ebb-aa60-51b57c977b1e
ArtikelListe:
ArtikelListe[1].Anzahl:0
ArtikelListe[2].Anzahl:1
ArtikelListe[3].Anzahl:0
submitButton:Nächste
```

I wonder why just partial data is sent withon the http post and why all my list items are null. I tried to render by for and foreach. same result.

Any ideas? I'm helpless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collection indexers must start at zero and be consecutive (unless you include an `Index` property).Because of your `if` statements, you are not necessarily generating a control for the property `Anzahl`. Looking at your header information, you do not have a value for `ArtikelListe[0].Anzahl` which means that the first item must have either `IstKategorie=true` or `MitAnzahl=false`. You can correct this by adding a hidden input so a value posts back

```
@if (Model.ArtikelListe[i].IstKategorie)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Artikelname)<br />  
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Information)
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl) // add this
}
else
{
  if (Model.ArtikelListe[i].MitAnzahl)
  {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl, new { @class = "field text fn" })
  }
  else
  {
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl) // add this         
  }
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Artikelname)<br />  
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Information)
}
```

Alternatively you can add an `Index` property which the `DefaultModelBinder` uses to match up collection items that are non-consecutive

```
@if (Model.ArtikelListe[i].IstKategorie)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Artikelname)<br />  
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Information)
}
else
{
  if (Model.ArtikelListe[i].MitAnzahl)
  {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl, new { @class = "field text fn" })
    <input type="hidden" name="x.ArtikelListe.Index" value="@i" /> // add this manually
  }
  else
  {
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl)     
  }
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Artikelname)<br />  
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Information)
}
```

With the first option, it will post back all items. In the second case it will post back only items that meet the `if` conditions.

Note as Sergey noted, you need to also remove `<input type="hidden" name="ArtikelListe" />`

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ArtikelListe" />
```

When POST request is sent back:

```
ArtikelListe:
ArtikelListe[1].Anzahl:0
ArtikelListe[2].Anzahl:1
ArtikelListe[3].Anzahl:0
```

Then `ArtikelListe` overrides value for the list and that's why it's always null. 
So you just need to rename your hidden field to some another name to not conflict with existing names.

Here is working example based on your MVC code in DotNetFiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/BCXduq

You can click RUN, then enter some values in two input fields in the right bottom box, and click Save button. And then it will display model that server received in POST as JSON text.

Comment: Thank you so far! If I remove, the entire collection is null on post. I'll check your code now.

Comment: If I remove or rename the hidden field name. That's what I wanted to say :-)

Comment: Your code works fine. But I still have an empty collection in my code. Anything else you changed? I just can't get it ...

Comment: Check DotNetFiddle link that i specified. It works there, `Anzahl` parameter comes fine to server side and collection has 2 items the same as on UI. Maybe you have different code that affect it?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys.

The problem was, that I did the testing with the script from the Fiddle. In this code

```
Model.ArtikelListe[i].MitAnzahl
```

was always true.

In case it is not true, the value "Anzahl" was not bound to a control containing a value (but just a label).

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ArtikelListe[i].Anzahl)
```

As soon as I inserted a hidden field within that scope and bound the "Anzahl" value to it, the post returned with all the data I expected.

Thanks anyway. I learned a lot!

Comment: Wow. I give you the detailed and correct answer and instead of accepting it you post this. Not even an up vote. Best of luck getting any help in the future.

Comment: Stephen, sorry for my fault. It's been a long time since, so I don't know if I missed your answer or simply didn't know better.

Next time please ask before you shoot. Thanks.