# Post a collection of input models ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC

Tags: c#

How can I fill with data and post a IEnumerable of input models in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC?

Especially I have difficulty making the view. Is there a way to collect the input data in the view with

```
@model ReservationCreateInputModel
```

Thanks!

```
public class ReservationCreateInputModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Select reservation type")]
    public ReservationType ReservationType { get; set; }

    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TouristCreateInputModel> Tourists { get; set; }
}

public class TouristCreateInputModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Child or Adult")]
    public TouristType TouristType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Personal Number")]
    public ulong PersonalNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Passport Number")]
    public ulong PassportNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If they haven't changed anything in this area you have to index the collection parameters with square brackets [], have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328149/asp-net-mvc-4-collection-is-null-on-post

Comment: Show some code here, how you posting data from views? because there is dozens of way to posting data from view.

Comment: It gives me a compile error with this code below https://pastebin.com/uqnGwd6F

Comment: By changing the IEnumarable collection to IList everithing is OK. Thanks